# loop through table to display all images where register_id = ? in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

i've been working on a project for a while now using CodeIgniter. I want to display all images of same $register_id from the database with a foreach loop on the view.php.

**Controller:**

```
public function view($register_id = NULL){

    $data['image'] = $this->image_model->get_all_images($register_id);

    if(empty($data['image'])){
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['image']['register_id'];

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('portfolios/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

**Model**

```
public function get_all_images($register_id = FALSE){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('images', array('register_id' => $register_id));
            return $query->row_array();
    }
```

**view.php**

```
<?php foreach ($image as $img) : ?>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h3><?php echo $image['title']; ?></h3>
    <div class="img-box">
        <img class="post-thumb" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/portfolios/<?php echo $image['register_id'];?>/<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
    </a></div>
```

Shows same image 14 times..

> query works perfectly on phpmyadmin & shows diff. images..

Comment: typo!! <?php foreach ($image as $img) : ?>

Comment: it runs, but it only shows same image multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

change your forloop variable. and its value variable too. may be solve.

```
 <?php foreach ($image as $value){?>
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <h3><?php echo $value['title']; ?></h3>
    <div class="img-box">
        <img class="post-thumb" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/portfolios/<?php echo $value['register_id'];?>/<?php echo $value['url']; ?>">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: it runs, but it only shows same image 14 times, & its constant even if i add or delete in db.

Comment: Kay , how is this possible ,? you were passing $data['image'] and you are using $images to iterate the loop , have you notice that or not ?

Comment: follow the MVC structure

Comment: you also have 

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: images
Filename: portfolios/view.php

Comment: i did this  <?php foreach ($image as $value) : ?> after that  same image 14 times..

Comment: print last query and test on mysql

Comment: and your code for model is for both row_array and result_array please correct your logic first , what are you trying to implement .

Comment: what i am trying is user uploads multiple images, one image of every user is shown on index after clicking image all the images of user are shown by register_id..
the query works perfectly on phpmyadmin ..

Comment: then you should add your full details in your question .